# How to use polymer-component in an ionic 2 application

Tags: polymer, ionic2, web-component

I am trying to use a polymer component in my application. and I have to use "webcomponentsready" event listener in my ionic 2 application. webcomponentsready is not calling when I keep it inside a ionic component. Is there any solution for this?

Seeing some example with angular2 but I can not use it in my application.

Comment: can you show some code? is webcomponents.js downloaded?

Comment: Thanks for showing the support...
It has got fixed for me.I downloaded webcomponent.js and included the webcomponentready event-listener for handling the events of my polymer component. Actually that was creating the problem.

I just removed the  webcomponentready and started using handler directly.